# 'NET USE' works in CMD but not in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line, drive, net-use

This command will work in CMD if I copy and paste it from my batch file to CMD.  When I run my batch file, it tells me access is denied (System Error 5).  Any idea what I need to do to fix this?

```
NET USE * "\\server\folder\" "password" /USER:domain\username
```

Comment: you shouldn't have to surround your pathword with `"`

Comment: That depends on what characters are present in the password.

Answer (score 2):

If the password happens to contains a percent character, double-up on the percent character to "escape" it.  So command:

```
NET USE X: \\Myserver\Myshare /user:Mydomain\John Ha322%%xb%%
```

would be written into the batch file if the password were "Ha322%xb%"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (Im assuming that * is a drive letter, fill in the angle braces):

```
net use <driveLetter>: "\\<servername>\<sharepath>" /u:<domain>\<user> <password>
```

make sure that the script is running under a context or interactive session.
So, example you are running the task as a job (schedule task). Make sure that the task is running under
a user account (not the SYSTEM account) and that "Don't store password" is unchecked in the schedule task properties.

Comment: Did you try running as administrator? (Bypass UAC)
And what windows version are you running?

Comment: Clicked on "Run as Administrator" on CMD and ran my batch (to get system errors), now instead of "System Error 5", we have progressed to "System error 86" network password is not correct.  Keep in mind this password is correct and works when I copy and paste this command directly to CMD.

Comment: Do you have any AV?
That will be a difference  between a script and a command prompt security settings. Try disabling he AV/FW temporarily.

Comment: This server is on a local network that is not connected to the internet. No AV or FW.

Comment: Does the password contain a `"` character? If it does, you will need to escape it in the string on the command line.

Comment: No, passwords are only characters and numbers.

Comment: Use the ShowArgs.exe utility from [this article](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell) and make sure the `net use` command line is actually correct. (Substitute 'ShowArgs' with 'net' to see the command line PowerShell is really running.)

Comment: `*` is legal for the drive argument. It tells the `net use` command to take the next available drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

If it's *System Error 5* then you should run cmd.exe as administrator.

But *System Error 86* occurred when you type username without domain. The simplest way is to type `/u:remoteIPaddressORremoteComputerName\username`. It is about NTLM authentication on Windows 7+.

Answer (score 0):

If the password ends in a ! it will not work and will do this.  Error 5 or Error 86 for some reason.

Comment: is this supposed to be an answer? or a comment on another post?